# Count "getElementById" in PHP

Tags: php, count, getelementbyid, getelementsbytagname

Need to showup the Qty of "IDs" or "Class" from a Site in my header.

It a job-site, i want to count the IDs or class of my Job Listings and show the number in my header (Menu).

How is it possible? With "getElementsByTagName" it works like a charme. Tried with "H3" Tags, but i have to many h3 on the site, so the qty / number is not correct.

my code now:

```
<?php
$htmlString = file_get_contents('https://www.mywebsite.de/unternehmen/jobs/');

//Create a new DOMDocument object.
$htmlDom = new DOMDocument;

//Load the HTML string into our DOMDocument object.
@$htmlDom->loadHTML($htmlString);


//Extract all h3 elements / tags from the HTML.
$h3Tags = $htmlDom->getElementsByTagName('h3');

$jobanzahl = $htmlDom->getElementById('jobtitel')->nodeValue;

echo "Total H3 Tags: ". count($h3Tags)."<br/>";
```

Comment: An ID is unique, how do you want to count it? Even if nothing prevents you from using the same ID several times, most DOM parsers probably do not take that into account (and even if they would, how do you count something that's meant to be unique ?).

Comment: _"It a job-site, i want to count the IDs or class of my Job Listings and show the number in my header (Menu)."_ - if your code creates this listing in the first place, then it should also know how many jobs there are at some point. This should probably rather not be done by parsing the already created output afterwards in a second step, but be determined at the point where the data is accumulated.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  The question states *"With "getElementsByTagName" it works like a charm"* but then states *"i have to many h3 on the site, so the qty / number is not correct"*.  Which is it?  Does `getElementsByTagName` correctly identify all of the target elements or not?  What is the specific problem you are observing?  What input is used?  What output is produced?  What output is expected?  Why?

Comment: My first thought was to count the H3 tags to get the number of job listings, and output this as a number in the header.

The second thought was to give the headers an "ID" or "Class", and then count them. 

Or do you have a good idea how else I can count the titles? Or should I assign a different "H-Tag" to the job listings, and then just let them count?

Comment: How many `<h3>` can a page have that the "_qty / number is not correct_"? Why would that not be correct?

Comment: @brombeer it should be 13 listings (Job). However, 24 are output via PHP. Because on the page itself further down H3 tags are used.

Comment: I guess a job listing site has a database ? It would be easier to SELECT COUNT ... WHERE [conditions] than to use tags and ids...

Comment: @AlexandreMartin its a simple Wordpress Page. So yeah, should be in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier to use the SELECT COUNT with your database, because you can manage which job offers are active and which are not. You can also ORDER BY starting date if you wish !

Here is the dataset I used for this example :

[image]

Each job has a unique id (int) as a primary key, a title (varchar), a description (text), a starting date (date) and a status (active or not - boolean). You can archive inactive offers for monthly or yearly reports, but you must count only active ones.

At first, I display the offers on a very basic html page :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM job";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);  

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();

echo "<h1>JOBS</h1>";
echo "<br>";

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      
      echo "<h2>" . $row['title'] .  "</h2>";
      echo "<p>" . $row['description'] .  "</p>";
      echo "<p><small>Starting on : " . $row['start_date'] .  "</small></p>";
      echo "<hr>";
    
  }
    
}
```

And then, I count and display the number of active offers :

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM job WHERE isActive = 1";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
    
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      
    echo "<p>There are " . $row['c'] . " offers</p>";
    
}
```

Here is the final result :

[image]

Finally, you should look at this codepen to circle the result :

https://codepen.io/jnbruno/pen/vNpPpW

[image]